# NameError: global name 'this_submit' is not defined

Tags: python

The following function seems really simple, but I keep getting:

> NameError: global name 'this_submit' is not defined.

Ideas?

```
def sort_nodes():

host_list=Popen(hosts_cmd.split(),stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
exec_list=Popen(exec_cmd.split(),stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
if submit_cmd == '':
    submit_list = [x for x in host_list if x not in exec_list]
else:
    submit_list=Popen(submit_cmd.split(),stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
for host in host_list:
    if host in exec_list:
        this_exec == 'Exec'
    else:
        this_exec == ''
    if host in submit_list:
        this_submit == 'Submit'
    else:
        this_submit == ''
    output="%s,%s,%s\n" % (host,this_submit,this_exec)
    ofile.write(output)
```

Comment: I think you want to use `=` rather than `==`

Answer (score 1):

the correct syntax is:

```
this_submit = 'Submit'
```

and

```
this_submit = ''
```

In python the single `=` is the assignment operator.

`==` checks if the value of two operands are equal or not, if yes then condition becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote `==` instead of `=`. fix it and everything will be fine.